# C# Entity Framework: Narrow results with a field value

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I just started using EF, and heres what I have:

dataEntity = new ThisProject.Data.Entities();

listBoxProjects.DataSource = dataEntity.projects;

This does insert all projects in the ListBox, but I want to narrow the results. I have an integer variable named clientID, and the projects table has a field named clientid, how can I narrow the results?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try a linq query:

```
var query = from project in dataEntity.projects
            where project.clientID = TARGET_ID
            select project;

listBoxProjects.DataSource = query;
```

Comment: don't forget the `.ToList` to fire off the query, otherwise if your UI is paging through the results you will fire a query each time (unless you have lazy loading disabled, but that's another issue).

Comment: I am getting the error: "cannot convert lambda express to type string" on the word 'where' from your code above. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: See my response below for a couple small things that I ran into.

Answer (score 0):

While scmccart gave me an answer that was nearly correct, I thought I should post as a separate answer to help anybody who looks at this in the future.

Here is what I ended up with:

```
dataEntity = new ThisProject.Data.Entities();

var query = from project in dataEntity.projects
            where project.client.id == clientID
            select project;

listBoxProjects.DataSource = query.ToList();
```

There are two differences with my answer:
1. Two == instead of one, which caused a little bit of a headache.
2. Added the .ToList() per RPM1984's suggestion.

I am pretty new to Stackoverflow, but I hope it lets me give scmccart credit for the answer after I make this post.